# Import a single value from Access into Excel (without the column heading)

Tags: excel, ms-access

I would love to know how to import a single value from my Access database into an Excel cell.
Alternatively removing the header would be a good start.

The query

```
SELECT SUM(DEMANDS) AS TOTAL FROM [DB PROD]
```

gives me a header named TOTAL and, right below it, the sum I'm interested in. I use this query from within Excel (Data > Get External Data > From Access). How can I only get the sum in a single Excel cell?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried till now and what error message are you getting (If any)

Comment: If have got no errors. Once I type in the request in the appropriate field in excel, I get a blank header and the value i'm interested in.

Comment: You missed the 1st part of my comment above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal would be to put your existing query on a different Sheet, say `Sheet2`, so the column header appears in `Sheet2!A1` and the value appears in `Sheet2!A2`. Then reference the value cell from elsewhere in the Excel document. (The formula will look something like `=Table_test.accdb[TOTAL]`.)

If you had several queries you could presumably keep them together (side by side) on the same sheet. You could also hide the query sheet so the "magic" would be more transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are doing, but, in order to read Access data from Excel, you need to do the following:

- programmaticaly open a connexion in your Excel code, pointing to your
  access database (let's say an ADO connexion for example)
- then execute your 'SELECT' through this connection, using the ADODB.command object. That will return the requested value
- another option would be to open a local recordset in Excel,based on your SQL intruction, and read the value.
- Then do not forget to close your connexion

Comment: I'm doing just that (point 1 and 2). I would like to have a single value but I also get the header (TOTAL).

Comment: Are you writing something like myCell.value = mySelectCommand.execute?

Comment: I'm not even doing it via VBA, i'm only making this query inside a single cell hoping to get the expected result inside of it

Comment: Well I did not know this was possible! You mean you are writing the query as the content of a cell in Excel? And Excel is executing it automatically when you press F9?

Comment: No I'm only adding a connection to an access database (DB PROD) on which i'm making the above query. I'm selecting a single cell as output but i get two cells, the header and the one i'm interested in.

Comment: So the query is in an Access database, and, when executed, it is diplayed with a column title and a field with a value? I do not get it: you are telling me that your process is populating two Excel cells with the result of an access query? Without any VBA coding? How does it work?

Comment: Philippe: See [Connect an Access database to your workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/connect-an-access-database-to-your-workbook-HA102840045.aspx).